# Best Practice to Avoid Too Many If Statements in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsdictionary, llvm

You all might have came across the scenarios like the following ones:

```
-(int) fightMath(int one, int two) {

if(one == 0 && two == 0) { result = 0; }
else if(one == 0 && two == 1) { result = 0; }
else if(one == 0 && two == 2) { result = 1; }
else if(one == 0 && two == 3) { result = 2; }
else if(one == 1 && two == 0) { result = 0; }
else if(one == 1 && two == 1) { result = 0; }
else if(one == 1 && two == 2) { result = 2; }
else if(one == 1 && two == 3) { result = 1; }
else if(one == 2 && two == 0) { result = 2; }
else if(one == 2 && two == 1) { result = 1; }
else if(one == 2 && two == 2) { result = 3; }
else if(one == 2 && two == 3) { result = 3; }
else if(one == 3 && two == 0) { result = 1; }
else if(one == 3 && two == 1) { result = 2; }
else if(one == 3 && two == 2) { result = 3; }
else if(one == 3 && two == 3) { result = 3; }

return result;
```

}

In short, how to effectively simplify the above scenario in Objective-C's ambience?

Any Suggestions/Ideas/Solutions ? 
Cheers :)

**Edit:** For reference , scenario taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501230/too-many-if-statements?newsletter=1&nlcode=194608%7C5bc9).I hope this question might save even one sec of needy developer.

Comment: Have you tried a switch statement? Or are you looking for something else? http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement

Comment: Why don't you use one of the answers to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501230/too-many-if-statements that you linked to? - It should be easy to translate the proposed Java solutions to C or Objective-C.

Comment: What else can be added that is not in the thread you are referring to?

Comment: @MartinR: Note: I stated here that in objective c environment , I need the solution. If you can then post the solution rather than negating

Comment: @itechnician: I don't know what you mean by "negating" (but I did *not* downvote your question). - I have simply suggested that you try one of the already available solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective C is built over C. So any good C solution will be also appropriate for Objective C. Like

```
int result[][4] = {
    { 0, 0, 1, 2 },
    { 0, 0, 2, 1 },
    { 2, 1, 3, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 3 }
};
return result[one][two]
```

As I know there is no Objective C - specific good practices for such problems.

Comment: Thanks for consideration.I needed the solution in Objective C because our MAC based tool app was running on Ojbective C based Architecture and for adding 'C' language instructions we need to have more 2^16 memory.