# Decreasing multiple IF ELSE conditions in Unix, Implementing array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

Currently I have below script to check if corresponding services are running on my server or not using some internal logic. Please find code snippet below:

```
MY_SERVER_ID=X22 //stored somewhere in profile of the servers

if [ "$MY_SERVER_ID" = "X11" -o "$MY_SERVER_ID" = "X22" -o "$MY_SERVER_ID" = "X33" ]
then

##do xx

     echo "  Service 1 : Running "

fi

if [ "$MY_SERVER_ID" = "X11" -o "$MY_SERVER_ID" = "X22" ]
then

##do xx

     echo "  Service 2 : Running "

fi
```

Now as all servers do not run all the services the If conditions become a lot more unreadable/ unnecessary complex. Currently I have 10+ servers and 8+ services where different services run on different servers. Also in future any service can be invoked/ start running on a particular node it wasn't running before in which case I have to go and change the script again.

I understand that in case of any change I definitely have to change the script and update in all the servers however I would like to make the process less painful than it already is.

I can implement something like an array that is defined at the start of the script to point out whether a given service runs on a particular node or not. Something I picked up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501230/too-many-if-statements?rq=1) question on stackoverflow.

I know multi dimensional arrays could be easily implemented in C but as I am quite new to shell scripting I would like to know if there is any possibility to make my script more readable and easily editable!!!

Comment: Shell doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays or other complex data structures. Do you really have to use shell for this?

Comment: Well actually, BASH doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays, but ksh does (and also compound variable). That said it's possible to use several arrays to emulate them if I may say. Depends on the type of data you have in mind/need and their different relationship.

Comment: bash supports associative arrays (maps) with `declare -A`. Values can be arrays.

Comment: Side note: why implement it yourself when you can use deployment tools like ansible and puppet and monitoring tools like zabbix or graphite or nagios or prometheus

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately I need to do it in shell only. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @KamilCuk Noted will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all your `if` checks are with the same variable, you can simplify it to `case`

```
case "$MY_SERVER_ID" in
X11|X22|X33)
    echo "Service 1 running" ;;
esac
```

`bash` doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, but you could use a space-delimited string as a substitute for a second dimension, as long as the values are simple.

```
declare -A services
all_services=([X11]="1 2" [X22]="1 2" [X33]="1")
services=${all_services[$MY_SERVER_ID]}
for i in $services; do
    echo "Service $i running"
done
```

Another possibility is storing the data in a JSON file and using the `jq` utility to parse it and extract values. This more elaborate version is left as an exercise for the reader (I'm not really very experienced with this tool).

Comment: I tried something like `for ((i=0; i<${n_services}; i++ )); do eval service_$i=$((1<<$i)); done` and testing with `.. if (( $((${!server} & ${!checkservice} )) > 0 )) .. ` but that is much too complex. I upvoted your short solution, that might be enhanced into a config file.